# Arcanedev\LaravelNestedSet\NodeTrait appendToNode() error

Tags: php, laravel

I am using the nested set for the first time with [arcanedev/laravel-nestedset](https://github.com/ARCANEDEV/LaravelNestedSet).
I am following a [tutorial](https://appdividend.com/2018/04/30/nested-set-in-laravel-tutorial/)  and setup my model accordingly. But when I call the `create` method it gives me following error.

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError thrown with message "Argument 1 passed to App\Models\AmazonCategoryIndices::appendToNode() must be an instance of Arcanedev\LaravelNestedSet\Contracts\Nodeable, instance of App\Models\AmazonCategoryIndices given, called in E:\TestProjects\pld-v4-admin\vendor\arcanedev\laravel-nestedset\src\NodeTrait.php on line 1074".

The data I am using is the same as it is in tutorial.

Here is my Model

==================================

```
namespace App\Models;
use Arcanedev\LaravelNestedSet\NodeTrait;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class AmazonCategoryIndices extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'amazon_category_indices';
   protected $guarded = [];   
   use NodeTrait;
}
```

==================================

```
foreach ($shops as $key => $value) {
  AmazonCategoryIndices::create($value);
}
```

Comment: Your tutorial's referring [lazychaser/laravel-nestedset](https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset) but In your code I see [ARCANEDEV/LaravelNestedSet](https://github.com/ARCANEDEV/LaravelNestedSet)

Comment: "ARCANEDEV/LaravelNestedSet" package uses "lazychaser/laravel-nestedset " at its backend.

Comment: I'm not sure about your statement https://github.com/ARCANEDEV/LaravelNestedSet/blob/master/composer.json#L18

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, the parameter passed to `App\Models\AmazonCategoryIndices::appendToNode()` is an instance of `App\Models\AmazonCategoryIndices` while it expects an instance of `Arcanedev\LaravelNestedSet\Contracts\Nodeable`

So, adding the contract `Arcanedev\LaravelNestedSet\Contracts\Nodeable` in your model should resolve your error.

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Arcanedev\LaravelNestedSet\NodeTrait;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Arcanedev\LaravelNestedSet\Contracts\Nodeable;

class AmazonCategoryIndices extends Model implements Nodeable
{
   protected $table = 'amazon_category_indices';
   protected $guarded = [];   
   use NodeTrait;
}
```

When you said:  *"ARCANEDEV/LaravelNestedSet" package uses "lazychaser/laravel-nestedset " at its backend.*

...It's not. They are two different packages and doesn't work the same. Arcanedev credited lazychaser for his work on which he probably used a lot of resources.
Now that's been said, I wouldn't recommend using arcanedev's package since it doesn't seems to be maintenained.